# How do js plug-ins make functions in IIFE accessible?

Tags: javascript

For example jQuery's code starts with `(function(){`,so it's functions shouldn't be accessible from external files,but how do they make them accessible? 
I tried creating `1.js,2.js` and here is the code of 1.js

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    function aa(){
        alert();
        console.log('a');
        return 1;
    }
})();
```

and 2.js

```
function b(){
    aa();
}
```

Now when i run `b()` it returns the error that `aa()` was not found,even though i added them both to the HTML file.

Comment: jQuery and other libraries make explicit assignments to properties of `window`.

Comment: @Pointy how do i make that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you seem to be confused between how jQuery is *written* versus how it is *used*. `$(function () { })` is a way to *use* jQuery (and it's not an IIFE, BTW).

Secondly, jQuery is accessible because it assigns `$` and `jQuery` (which both refer to the same thing) to `window`. All of its methods are properties on that `$` object.

You can do the same thing:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function aa() {
    alert();
    console.log('a');
    return 1;
  }

  function ab() {
    return 2;
  }

  window.myStuff = {
    aa: aa,
    ab: ab
  };
})();

(function() {

  function b() {
    var sum = myStuff.aa() + myStuff.ab();

    console.log(sum);
  }

  b();

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

IIFEs are functions like any other. This means you can pass parameters into IIFEs as you would in any other function, e.g.:

```
(function(num) { console.log(num * 2); })(3); // logs 6
```

But instead of just passing in a number like I did above, you can also pass in objects:

```
(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.foo + 1); // logs 124
})({ foo: 123 });
```

Since you can pass an object, you can also pass a variable that points to an object:

```
var outsideObj = { foo: 123 };

(function(insideObj) {
    insideObj.foo = insideObj.foo + 1;
})(outsideObj);

console.log(outsideObj.foo); // logs 124
```

Keep in mind that in JavaScript, the `window` variable is a global *and* it's an object. Lo and behold:

```
(function(insideObj) {
    insideObj.example = function() {
        console.log('example called');
    };
})(window);

window.example(); // logs 'example called'
```

So, the gist is that you pass in an object, then the object is modified inside the IIFE.